# How replace England flag with french flag in opencart version 2.2.0.0

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

i want change this two flags with french and morocco flags. how i can do that? i search in admin panel but there is no option allow do this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7xUx.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! This question looks more like an administration or configuration matter related to OpenCart. SO is made for technical/code questions. Therefore, I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. "Questions regarding third party extensions, templates, or how to do what in administration should not be asked here - use the developer's support, OpenCart support team or OpenCart forums for this kind of question."

Comment: You must download your desired language pack, and install it.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to edit the language you will find the option for image*.

Please see the image that I am uploading.

[image]

You can change image from en.png to whatever.png and you will find the flags over here

> catalog\view\theme\YOUR_THEME_NAME\images\flags